# Passing Thread Control Facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I am trying the [Handover Protocal](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol) for my bot but I am not able to get
about `passing thread control` though I read the documentation still, I am confused

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{"id":"<PSID>"},
  "target_app_id":123456789,
  "metadata":"String to pass to secondary receiver app" 
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/pass_thread_control?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

**Example pass_thread_control Event**

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PAGE_ID>"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "pass_thread_control":{
    "new_owner_app_id":"123456789",
    "metadata":"Additional content that the caller wants to set"
  }
}
```

I am trying to know what is `PSID` here and what can be `target_app_id`.
can anyone help me with proper example.

Comment: `PSID` is the page-scoped user id, same as it is in any other place in Messenger API. And target_app_id is the id of the app that you want to pass control to, obviously. That can be another bot app, or just the normal “page inbox” functionality, which also has its own specific app id. The documentation describes this in sufficient detail IMHO.

Comment: I upvoted this. This shouldn't be downvoted, the documentation isn't the best for their API so I understand your frustration. Fortunately they released a nice tutorial explaining https://blog.messengerdevelopers.com/tutorial-adding-live-chat-via-the-page-inbox-with-the-handover-protocol-aea2ede75fd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a bit to figure out, so I totally understand your frustration! There isn't adequate documentation when it comes to working with the handover protocol.

My current use case is a bot that offers the option to speak to a representative if it's unable to understand the user. This is done through the use of a postback button, which means the handover is activated by the user. After the user clicks on the button, the following code is run:

```
graph.setAccessToken(<YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN>);
graph.setAppSecret(<YOUR_APP_SECRET>);
graph.setVersion("2.12");

graph.post(
    `me/pass_thread_control?access_token=${functions.config().messenger.token}`, 
    handoverMessage, 
    (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('HANDOVER ERROR:', err);
            return;
        }                    
        console.log('HANDOVER SUCCESS:', res);
});
```

The handoverMessage variable is where you will place the psid and target_app_id:

```
let handoverMessage = {
    "recipient": {
        "id": <PSID>
     },
     "target_app_id": <YOUR_TARGET_APP_ID>
}
```

Calling this code will handover the control of the conversation to whatever your target_app_id is.

If you're wondering what 'graph' is, it is a node package called 'fbgraph' that I've found very useful when dealing with the facebook graph api. It's certainly not the only wrapper and there are likely better packages out there, but it has worked for me up to now.

Comment: yeh thanks, but i figured it out on my way, but can you share your code for handover protocol i want to look at for some referances

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!